# ReactJS - element type is invalid expected a string but got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-lock-component) to use scroll lock on a react component.

When I run a build I get the following error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
```

I'm importing the package as suggested, I've checked the source file of the package to make sure it's not named something else and as it is exported:

```
exports.default = ScrollLock;
```

How can I resolve this?

Here is my component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import ScrollLock from 'react-scroll-lock-component';

import MobileSVG from '../../../assets/svg/icons/Mobile_Icon_Option2.svg';
import TabletSVG from '../../../assets/svg/icons/Tablet_Icon_Option2.svg';
import DesktopSVG from '../../../assets/svg/icons/Desktop_Icon_Option2.svg';

import styles from './styles.css';

const deviceIcons = {'mobile': MobileSVG, 'tablet': TabletSVG, 'desktop': DesktopSVG};

import BackToTopButton from '../BackToTopButton';

export default class ProductComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.scroll = this.scroll.bind(this);
    }

    scroll(y){
        y > 0 ? (
           this.slider.slickNext()
        ) : (
           this.slider.slickPrev()
        )
    }

    componentWillMount(){
        window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
            //this.scroll(e.wheelDelta);
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {productData} = this.props

        //Slider settings
        const settings = {
            dots: true,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 500,
            fade: true,
            arrows: false,
            centerMode: true,
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
        }

        //Slider items
        const sliderItems = productData.map((obj, i) => {
            return (
                <div className="product-component row" key={i}>
                    <div className="product-component-image-wrap col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                        <span className="product-heading">{obj.category}</span>
                        <div className="product-detail-wrap">
                            <img className="product-component-image" src={`${process.env.DB_URL}${obj.image}`} />
                            <ul className="list-device-support">
                                {obj.categoryDeviceSupport.map((obj, i) => {
                                    return (<li key={i}>
                                        <span className="svg-icon">
                                            <ReactSVG path={deviceIcons[obj.value]} />
                                        </span>
                                        <span className="product-label">{obj.label}</span>
                                    </li>)
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="product-component-info col-xs-12 col-sm-3"> 
                        <span className="align-bottom">{obj.title}</span>
                        <p className="align-bottom">{obj.categoryBrief}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        });
        return (
            <div className="product-component-wrap col-xs-12">
                <ScrollLock>
                    <Slider {...settings} ref={slider => this.slider = slider}>
                        {sliderItems}
                    </Slider>
                    <BackToTopButton scrollStepInPx="50" delayInMs="7" />
                </ScrollLock>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ProductComponent.propTypes = {
    productData: PropTypes.array
};

ProductComponent.defaultProps = {
    productData: []
};
```

Comment: What happens if you change `import ScrollLock from 'react-scroll-lock-component';` to `import { default as ScrollLock } from 'react-scroll-lock-component';`?

Comment: Unfortunately the same error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

Comment: Are you using webpack to bundle your app? Would it be possible to create a repo demonstrating this issue?

Comment: Yes using webpack to bundle. Unfortunately not as it's a commercial project.

Comment: I've got an idea its to do with babel/webpack not dealing with mixed requires and imports correctly. Could you create a repo with nothing other than the issue?

Comment: Try putting the propTypes and defaultProps as static methods does it cause the same issue then?

Comment: @rrd I'm not quite sure what you mean by this? It's an imported package not a variable so I'm unsure how this would be available in propTypes?